# $.getJSON equivalent in Silverlight

Tags: c#, jquery, silverlight, web-services

I'm making the following call in jQuery, using jsonp as my data format, that I'd like to make directly in Silverlight:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.wordstream.com/authentication/login?callback=?',
    { 'username': un,
      'password': pw
}, function (loginResults) {
    API_SESSION_ID = loginResults['data']['session_id'];
    $.getJSON('https://api.wordstream.com/keywordtool/get_keywords?callback=?',
        { 'session_id': API_SESSION_ID,
          'seeds': keyword,
          'max_results': 20
    }, function (keywordResults) {
        for (i = 0; i < +keywordResults['data'].length; i++) {
            Keywords[i] = keywordResults['data'][i][0];
        }
        return(Keywords);
    });
});
```

I tried something like this to handle the first $.getJSON (authenticating & returning my auth token):

```
WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("https://", System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
var client = new WebClient();
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.DownloadStringCompleted += new     
DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
client.DownloadStringAsync(loginEndpoint);
```

When I try and run this I get the following error inside my downloadstringcompleted eventhandler:

```
{System.Security.SecurityException: Security error.
at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass5.<EndGetResponse>b__4(Object sendState)
at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b__1(Object sendState)}
```

I've used WCF Ria Services in EF & SOAP services via .asmx files in the past, so I'm not a total stranger to the idea of web services. I am not sure if I need to be using the clientaccesspolicy or crossdomain files or not.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: I just hope you're not sending the `password` as plain text over the net ...

Comment: Notice the registerprefix is https. So no to plaintext.

Comment: still, it should be encoded first at least, never as normal text.Plus, always use `using()` when dealing with methods that implement the `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: If I'm passing in credentials to an endpoint URL that I don't control, wouldn't they have to have a mechanism for decoding? Also - which method here implements IDisposable??

Comment: Also - is the issue here that the remote server may not have a crossdomain.xml file? I thought that was the point of using jsonp - for cross domain calls. I don't know how to use jsonp in silverlight...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you trying to do in this series of questions has become clearer to me now.

Unless `api.wordstream.com` includes a ClientAccessPolicy xml (or the Flash equivalent) you will not be able to make requests to this api from Silverlight.

You have two options:

- Call into Javascript to make these requests on behalf of the Silverlight app.
- Create WCF service to on your server to make these requests on behalf od the Silverlight app.

I would recommend the first approach, however don't use `getJSON`.  Instead use the standard `ajax` api in `JQuery` to fetch the JSON content asynchronously.  When the final JSON content is available (still in string form) call into Silverlight from Javasript passing in the string.

What would be preferable is to create the appropriate set of .NET classes and collections that match the data from the api.  You could then use `DataContractJsonSerialializer` to deserialize the received string into instances of your classes.

Sometimes creating a class structure can be a bit of a burden.  Another approach is to use the set of objects in the `System.Json` namespace starting with `JsonValue.Parse` to load up the set of JsonObjects from the string.  You can now navigate around the returned data using these `son objects and Linq where necessary.

Comment: I don't think javascript can get the string of an external resource. But it can execute it. So if you wrap the json in a bit of javascript you can get external json resources. That's the point of jsonp.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Anthony (do you ever sleep?). In the last question, when I was returning data from JS to Silverlight, I was trying to create .NET classes, but I realized that the json that contains the actual data I need is simply: "Data: '[a,z],[b,y]...[z,a]' - the data itself isn't in property:value format, it's simply a property called data and a value that's an array. I tried deserializing to keyvaluepair<string,int> (the formats returned) and that failed. I am using jObject & jArray to get the data returned from JS.

Comment: To confirm - you're saying that my current implementation - which calls JS from my Silverlight VM, returns the data & uses jObject & jArray to parse/navigate/linqify, is correct. Only modification would be to move from $.getJSON to $.ajax?

Comment: Scott: Yes I do sleep, I think I may have even been asleep when I posted this answer.  @CodeInChaos is quite correct my approach won't help because there isn't a way to get a JSONP request to return a string.  You could use JSON.Stringify before passing into Silverlight and then follow the rest of my answer.  However the effort of Stringify and then deserialising may not offset the cost of manipulating ScriptObject directly.

Answer (score 1):

Did a little digging and a test.

When you are calling an external domain, the cross-domain issue will occur and that's why you are seeing the `Security error`.

Remember that this is a Web application after all, it does run inside the browser!

To enable Silverlight to reach outside it's domain, give this article a try if you are doing a self hosted app.

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/03/07/enabling-cross-domain-calls-for-silverlight-apps-on-self-hosted-web-services.aspx

Comment: Yeah I mentioned the clientaccesspolicy/cross domain in my OP. The issue in my head was the fact that I didn't think those files were required on MY site. After further digging, it's true - it needs to be on the endpoint server.